# How to correctly update webapp when cron brings new data

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, real-time

my problem is the following: I have an application in ruby ​​on rails that I would like to update in realtime, second by second. I would not, however, overload the database unnecessarily (because too many users and small server). I would like the ruby ​​on rails application to be notified in some way by the mysql database when an update occurred in some datqabase table. It's possible?
I have a python script that in realtime could populate with new data the mysql tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. Won't the rails app get the updated data from the db on each request anyway? Are you caching the data? If that's the case just have the python script invalidate the cache.

Comment: Is it legit to request db everytime? If I have many and many users, will the db overcharge by requests?

Comment: I'd say you're better off hitting the db on every request for now. If the time comes and it becomes a bottleneck you can start thinking about caching.